# TV show or movie about a creature in a basement that can only be killed with a silver sword

Tags: story-identification, tv

So I saw the end of this show or movie. A creature is in a basement and a man is explaining that it can only be killed by a silver sword he has. It grabs a guy who was by the basement and drags him down. The creature comes out of the basement and the man protects the last survivors by doing a turning slice and killing the monster. I thought it was called The Silver Sword, but haven’t found anything on it.

Comment: What was the appearance of that creature? Did it look like a werewolf?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you watch this?  Where, and what language was it on?

Answer (score 6):

[Monsters](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094512/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_20) episode [Rouse him not](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0650870/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_20) from 1998.

From IMDB:

> A painter with strange visions who lives in an old cottage is visited
> by a warlock who used to live there. But his arrival wakes an ancient
> beast buried far below the cottage.

Alex Cord plays the warlock, [John Thunstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Thunstone), with the silver sword.

Full video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFDr_nOcKCQ).  Sword swingage at 19:10.